# Cloud Formation example template for ElastiCache Redis Global Store

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elasticache

I tried to follow this document https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-elasticache-globalreplicationgroup.html#cfn-elasticache-globalreplicationgroup-cacheparametergroupname, to create a global store for Redis in the ElastiCache. but I'm not able to achieve that. kindly share any examples related to this

```
  RedisGlobalReplication:
Type: AWS::ElastiCache::GlobalReplicationGroup
Properties: 
  AutomaticFailoverEnabled: true
  CacheNodeType: !Ref CacheNodeType
  EngineVersion: !Ref RedisEngineVersion
  GlobalNodeGroupCount: 1
  CacheParameterGroupName: 'default.redis5.0'
  GlobalReplicationGroupDescription: !Sub '${AWS::StackName}-Redis Global store'
  GlobalReplicationGroupIdSuffix: !Ref 'AWS::StackName'
  Members:
    - ReplicationGroupRegion: 'ap-south-1'
      Role: primary
  RegionalConfigurations: 
    - ReplicationGroupId: '1'
      ReplicationGroupRegion: 'ap-south-1'
      ReshardingConfigurations: 
        - NodeGroupId: '1'
          PreferredAvailabilityZones: 
            - ap-south-1a
            - ap-south-1b
```

Comment: What is your current template and why it does not work?

Comment: I updated the template here. But I'm not able to arrive at the right structure. Any example related to global data store Redis would be great

Comment: Any update on it .How we can add encryption to the data as I can't see any doc for this